# Reading File from Internal storage with No Read/Write Permissions?

Tags: android, file, file-io, permissions, file-permissions

I have a file on Internal Storage on the path e.g. `/data/data/<package name>/folder/myfile`
I don't have permissions to access this file but for my implementation I have to read this file. for this purpose I first run `su` command on the file and set permissions through `chmod` command to `777`and then try to access the file. but still show that file does not exist. Please tell how can I can get this file to read.

Following is what I am trying to do.

```
public void runChmodAndSU(String filePath)
  {
    Process chperm;
    try {
        chperm = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("chmod 777 "+ filePath +"\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();

        chperm.waitFor();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After running above code I check it this way:

```
 File myFile  = new File(filePath);

    if (myFile.exists())
    {
        Log.e("Success!", "myFile Exists");
    }
    else {
        Log.e("Failure!", "myFile Does not Exists");
    }
```

Please tell me how can I read this very file. Is there any other way to access files you don't have permissions to?

Comment: Is this file one that your app created?

Comment: @TronicZomB no ..it is a file from my another application.

Comment: Ok, don't know so much about that side of it then...

Answer (score 1):

You can't nor should you be allowed to access such files without the appropriate permissions set in AndroidManifest.xml for your application.

I can't tell if you were intending this to be a "hack android for me please?" question, or if you just don't know what android's uses-permission is about, but the way your question is worded, you really shouldn't be able to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

If **su** is working, try `chmod -R 777 /data/data/<package name>/`